# Sitecore 8.1 Controller Rendering Error

Tags: mvc-forms, controller

I am a newby and working on the Solutions Developer Course for Sitecore 8.2 online in Visual Studio with Sitecorerocks. Also just a heads up, very recently I had to rebuild this Visual Studio 2015 solution due to a corrupted .csproj file. So my question is:

Why am I getting this error message when trying to create a new Controller Rendering for SubscribeForm. It is setup to use a tested placeholder I have used for many other control renderings and there is no model associated since I am just trying to display the initial route(Index).

Error Message:
[image]

Sitecore Explorer: Created Controller rendering:
[image]

Sitecore Explorer: Presentation Rendering and place holders are setup like this for an events detail page:

[image]

Solution Explorer: Controller:

[image: Controller:]

Solution Explorer: Views/SubscribeForm/Index.cshtml:

[image]

Comment: Are the other controllers that are working as expected in the same namespace?

Comment: Yes all the controllers are in the same namespace.

Comment: @AndreaCronin ever get past this?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of potential issues here:

- Set the controller name to the fully qualified class name, e.g `MyProject.Controllers.SomeController, MyProject`
- Make sure the action name does not have the `/` in, it should just be `Index`
- It looks like you have not registered your controller with the IoC container. Sitecore 8.2 introduced a lot of new Dependency Injection features. But this meant that you would now have to register your controller with the container for Sitecore to be able to create it.

#### Registering your Controller

The easiest way to do this would be to create a `Configurator` class that implements `IServicesConfigurator`, and register your controller in there. Here is an example

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Sitecore.DependencyInjection;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class Configurator: IServicesConfigurator
    {
        public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddTransient<MyController>();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you have to create a patch include file that will tell Sitecore to use that `Configurator`. Here is an example of that:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <services>
            <configurator type="MyProject.Configurator, MyProject" />
        </services>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Once you have that setup, Sitecore will now know how to create your controller correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need the `/` before the action name in your rendering. Change `/Index` to `Index` and it should work properly.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I removed the / before the action name and still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you try renaming the post action in your controller? I wonder if Sitecore is getting confused about which action to use.

Comment: I just renamed it, I have even tried deleting the httpost section all together before, and this error still keeps occurring. To me it feels like, It can't even find/interact with the controller at all.

Comment: Can you try renaming the controller?

Answer (score -2):

Try putting the full type name of the controller in the highlighted field:

> events.tac.local.Controllers.SubscribeFormController,events

[image]

(Make sure that the assembly name is events or update it.)